# Cannot serve txt files on IIS in Windows Server 2016, 403 access denied

Tags: iis, windows-server-2016

Using IIS in Windows server 2016, files with the extension .txt are not served.

The resulting status code is 403, access denied.

Why?

The mime type `.txt` is listed in the server root with the mime type `text/plain`.
The default web site inherits it (together with every other mime type).
No override seems to be made when it comes to mime types.

I can add another mime type, put a file with the new (made up) extension and have it served as a text file.

I tried to remove the mime type and add it again (not using period before the suffix name).

No other file type seems to cause problems. It is just txt files, I even have support for php on the server.

## edit

In a comment, I was asked about which substatus error code I was getting. The log file shows lines like this:

```
2017-05-08 00:54:17 172.31.14.247 GET /foobar/1.txt - 80 - 2.94.45.4 Mozilla/3.0+(compatible;+Indy+Library) - 403 1 5 64
```

so the answer would be 403.1 (execute access forbidden). Is the IIS trying to execute txt-files?

Comment: what is the sub-status of your 403? check your IIS http logs.

Comment: Seems to be 403.1, question updated.

Comment: You should not get a 403.1 for a *.txt file, something is wrong with your configuration. Enable Failed Request tracing to find out what modules or handlers are running for the request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of IIS > *MIME Types*, revise IIS > [*Handler Mappings*](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771240(v=ws.10).aspx). There shouldn't be any (script) *Handler* associated with *Path* `*.txt`, but it should have (or fall back to "Static File" `*`):

- Path Type: **File or Folder**
- Module: `StaticFileModule,DefaultDocumentModule,DirectoryListingModule`
- In *Request Restrictions*, Verbs: All, Access: Read.

(IIS 7 documentation is up-to-date: the [`handlers` element](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/handlers) was not modified in IIS 10/8.5/8.0/7.5/7.0).